# Index out of range in tableView:canEditRowAt after batch delete In TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I was trying to implement a batch delete in my list my code kinda looks like this.

```
func deleteSelection() {
    var deletedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
    for (index, item) in self.itemsArray.enumerated().reversed() {
        if item.isSelected {
            self.itemsArray.remove(at: index)
            deletedIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        }
    }
    if !deletedIndexPaths.isEmpty {
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletedIndexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return self.itemsArray[indexPath.row].isEditable
}
```

I get an index out of range inside tableview:canEditRowAt
Is there a proper way to batch delete in tableView while implementing canEditRowAt

My current solution is to delete rows as the item is removed

```
func deleteSelection() {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    for (index, item) in self.itemsArray.enumerated().reversed() {
        if item.isSelected {
            self.itemsArray.remove(at: index)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

It now works, but shouldn't the original code also work?

Comment: Where do you get the error exactly? Post the stack trace and the code.

Answer (score -1):

The example code in the first case does not work becuase you never told the tableview to trigger the section and row count methods. This is done by beginUpdates and endUpdates methods and that is why your second example works.

```
func deleteSelection() {
    var deletedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    for (index, item) in self.itemsArray.enumerated().reversed() {
        if item.isSelected {
            self.itemsArray.remove(at: index)
            deletedIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        }
    }
    if !deletedIndexPaths.isEmpty {
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletedIndexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Also, in iOS 11, Apple introduced [performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates) to provide us a method method where we want to make multiple changes to the table view in one single animated operation, as opposed to several separate animations. You can use it for iOS 11 and above.

```
func deleteSelection() {
    var deletedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

    for (index, item) in self.itemsArray.enumerated().reversed() {
        if item.isSelected {
            self.itemsArray.remove(at: index)
            deletedIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        }
    }

    if !deletedIndexPaths.isEmpty {
        tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletedIndexPaths, with: .automatic)
        }) { (completed) in

        }
    }
}
```